# Distribute values of latest date over the group

Tags: sql

Here's my table:

```
Select ID, sum (VALUE), DATE FROM MYTABLE group by ID, DATE order by ID, DATE desc

ID    VALUE    DATE
1     23       2014-05
1     25       2014-04
1     22       2014-03
2     5        2014-05
2     8        2014-04
2     3        2014-03
3     32       2014-05
3     25       2014-04
```

I want add a new column and 'distribute' the VALUE of top (max) DATE over the group (ID), and get the following result (! one thing is vital though - the sum function is heavy, so I don't want to execute it twice):

```
ID    VALUE    DATE      NEW_COL
1     23       2014-05   23 
1     25       2014-04   23
1     22       2014-03   23
2     5        2014-05   5
2     8        2014-04   5
2     3        2014-03   5
3     32       2014-05   32
3     25       2014-04   32
```

Comment: Does your RDBMS supports analytic functions? `Max(Date) over(partition by id)`

Comment: Yes, it does support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id, SUM(value) AS value, date,
    FIRST_VALUE(SUM(value)) OVER 
        ( PARTITION BY id
          ORDER BY date DESC 
        ) AS new_col 
FROM 
    mytable
GROUP BY 
    id, date  
ORDER BY 
    id, date DESC ;
```

which is basically a compact form of this (your query and then the `FIRST_VALUE` on a second level):

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
        id, SUM(value) AS value, date
    FROM 
        mytable
    GROUP BY 
        id, date 
  )

SELECT 
    id, value, date,
    FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER 
        ( PARTITION BY id
          ORDER BY date DESC 
        ) AS new_col 
FROM 
    cte
ORDER BY 
    id, date DESC ;
```

Comment: the thing is that it executes the sum function twice.. that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: No, it does not execute the sum function twice. Why do you think it does? SQL optimizers are pretty smart on that. What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table #t
create table #t(id int,value int,date1 varchar(15))
insert into #t values(1,23,'2014-05'),
(1,25,'2014-04'),
(1,22,'2014-03'),
(2,5,'2014-05'),
(2,8,'2014-04'),
(2,3,'2014-03'),
(3,32,'2014-05'),
(3,25,'2014-04')

select id,value,date1,newid1=FIRST_VALUE(value) over(partition by id order by date1 desc) from #t
order by id
```

### <kbd>[sql server demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22032)</kbd>